# Object reference not set to an instance of an object --> Datagridview export to Excel

Tags: c#, excel, object, datagridview

I am busy developing a small application that will manage revenues. I go into a datagridview (through textbox ) data and they will be added in each other .

An "export" button is present, and it's all supposed to export to Excel. W**hen I tested with a line , it works. As soon as I have more than one line , I am entitled to this error:**

> object reference not set to an instance of an object.

When I leave Visual Studio, the Excel window appears to know if I want to save my workbook ... I do so, and it retains only a single line , even if I have created 10 .

I was inspired by this code , but good .. https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/How-to-Export-DataGridView-62f1f8ff

Here is my code

```
    public partial class addVente : Form
    {
        public addVente()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        // Bouton valider le nouvel enregistrement
        private void btnValider_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(txtName.Text, txtProduit.Text, float.Parse(txtPa.Text), float.Parse(txtPv.Text), float.Parse(txtComm.Text));

        }

        // On crée un nouveau mois
        private void btnNouveauMois_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult newMonth = MessageBox.Show("Feuille du mois bien sauvegardée?", "Commencer un nouveau mois", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

            if (newMonth == DialogResult.Yes)
                this.Close();
        }



        // Exporter vers Excel. Ne fonctionne pas correctemnet !!!!
        private void ExportToExcel()
        {
            // Creating a Excel object.
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet worksheet = null;

            try
            {

                worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;

                worksheet.Name = "ExportedFromDatGrid";

                int cellRowIndex = 1;
                int cellColumnIndex = 1;

                //Loop through each row and read value from each column.
                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
                    {
                        // Excel index starts from 1,1. As first Row would have the Column headers, adding a condition check.
                        if (cellRowIndex == 1)
                        {
                            worksheet.Cells[cellRowIndex, cellColumnIndex] = dataGridView1.Columns[j].HeaderText;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            worksheet.Cells[cellRowIndex, cellColumnIndex] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                        }
                        cellColumnIndex++;
                    }
                    cellColumnIndex = 1;
                    cellRowIndex++;
                }

                //Getting the location and file name of the excel to save from user.
                SaveFileDialog saveDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
                saveDialog.Filter = "Excel files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|All files (*.*)|*.*";
                saveDialog.FilterIndex = 2;

                if (saveDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    workbook.SaveAs(saveDialog.FileName);
                    MessageBox.Show("Enregistrement effectué !");
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                excel.Quit();
                workbook = null;
                excel = null;
            }

        }

        private void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ExportToExcel();
        }

        private void btnOuvrir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("en cours de développement");
        }


    }
```

Comment: On what line do you have the exception?

Comment: dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString(); is likely where the issue is -- debug and find out if there's actually a value there or if it's null

Comment: This is the fun part.... I didn't see where is the exception... not marked :/

Comment: @oppassum, you're right !

worksheet.Cells[cellRowIndex, cellColumnIndex] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();

https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=FR-FR&k=k(EHNullReference);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.2);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true

But I can't solve this problem.. Can you help? Thanks

Comment: No, you need to debug.